# How do I debug Resource #6 error in MSSQL?

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql, sql-server

I have a pair of radio buttons and I want to insert its value into my database in the form of `bit`. Following is the HTML code for the same.

```
<form  id="Form" method="post" class="overlay"  action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" >
<input type="hidden" id="Keyy" name="key" value="">
<label for="JRadioYes">Active? Yes</label> <input type="radio" id="JRadioYes" name="activeradio"<?php if (isset($ActiveValue) && $ActiveValue == "yes") echo "checked='checked' "; ?>value="yes"> 
        <label for="JRadioNo">No</label> <input type="radio" id="JRadioNo" name="activeradio"<?php if (isset($ActiveValue) && $ActiveValue == "no") echo "checked='checked' "; ?>value="no">
<input type="submit" id="submitter" name="sub" value="Submit!" onclick="decider(this)">
</form>
```

The following is the PHP code for inserting into the database

```
// Check if radio is submitted
if (isset ( $_POST ["activeradio"])) 
{
    //Extract values from $_POST and store in variables
    $select_radio = $_POST ["activeradio"];

    if ($select_radio == "yes") {
        $active_status = true;
        //I also tried assigning 1 instead of true
    }
    if ($select_radio == "no") {
        $active_status = false;
        //I also tried assigning 0 instead of false
    }

    if($_POST["key"] == "update")
    {
        try
        {
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
                alert('$active_status');
                </script>";
            $JobInt = intval($JobTypeID);
            $stmt = sqlsrv_query ( $conn, 'EXEC spEditThisJobType @Active = ?', array (
                $active_status
            ) );
        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
            echo "Error :". $e;
        }
        if($stmt != null)
        {
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Successfully Updated!$stmt');
            </script>";
        }
    }
}
```

I am able to get the alert which says Successfully Updated, but I am also getting Resource #6 error along with it. Also the database does not get updated.

What is the mistake I have done here? Please guide me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Surely not all of those tags are relevant.. (questions should focus on the problem, not the code for the general task / application in which the problem is manifested)

Comment: @user2864740 I added those tags for clarity, to show the flow of logic I am using.

Comment: Not all of the tags are relevant. eg. It is a JavaScript/HTML (client) issue or a PHP (server) issue, but not both. The current tag association is similar to saying heart is related to air because of worms. *Remove the tags that are unnecessary* when a [minimal problem test case is created](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the documentation for [`sqlsrv_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-query.php) - it returns a resource object, not the result of the query.

Therefore when you echo `"Successfully Updated!$stmt"`, the resource `$stmt` is converted to its string representation - `Resource #6`.

So you either need to remove `$stmt` from your echo, or do something with the resource such as reading the data using [`sqlsrv_fetch_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-fetch-array.php).

Comment: I found out that my user account did not have access to the needed database. So it was an access permission issue. Thank you for your response!